# Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue implementing `TextInputLayout` as my app crashes.

I created a UI using the XML below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Card number" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#53BD55"
            android:onClick="pay"
            android:text="Make Payment"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and also added this line to my dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

but my app still crashes with the error stack trace below:

```
Process: com.gambeat.mimo, PID: 5975
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gambeat.mimo/com.gambeat.mimo.paystack.paystack.activity.PaystackActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2805)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gambeat.mimo-L8Ypbdvmq-0sKhlFg587pg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gambeat.mimo-L8Ypbdvmq-0sKhlFg587pg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.gambeat.mimo-L8Ypbdvmq-0sKhlFg587pg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.gambeat.mimo.paystack.paystack.activity.PaystackActivity.onCreate(PaystackActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

Please what could the issue be?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891609/2711811

Comment: Meanwhile your first level <LinearLayout has no orientation. One will need to see your activity to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: Use com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0 instead of com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01

Answer (score 0):

Just check your App Theme and set it to `@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` if not.

Hope it works for you!